# windows phone 7, adding buttons to panel

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Following piece works very well in `silverlight`,

```
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanelInner" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanelInner">
            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />                        
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="Ok" Width="100"/>
                <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="No" Width="100"/>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

It just adds two buttons in the same row. 
When I try to do same from C#, it couldn't work.

Here is my c# code:

```
        Grid g1 = new Grid();
        //StackPanel innerSP = new StackPanel();
        ColumnDefinition cd1 = new ColumnDefinition();            
        ColumnDefinition cd2 = new ColumnDefinition();
        g1.ColumnDefinitions.Add(cd1);
        g1.ColumnDefinitions.Add(cd2);
        panel1.Children.Add(g1);
        Grid.SetColumn(buttonOk,0);
        Grid.SetColumn(buttonNo, 1);

        panel1.Children.Add(buttonOk);            
        panel1.Children.Add(buttonNo);           

        border.Child = panel1;

        // Set the Child property of Popup to the border 
        // which contains a stackpanel, textblock and button.
        p.Child = border;
```

Can someone tell me what has been wrong?

Comment: I'm trying example given here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup%28v=vs.95%29.aspx
All i wanted is ok, cancel buttons in same row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
Grid.SetColumn(buttonOk,0);
Grid.SetColumn(buttonNo, 1);
```

to this:

```
buttonOk.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);
buttonNo.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1);
```

If the buttons are supposed to be in the Grid columns (which would seem to make sense), then you should also change this:

```
panel1.Children.Add(buttonOk);
panel1.Children.Add(buttonNo);
```

to this:

```
g1.Children.Add(buttonOk);
g1.Children.Add(buttonNo);
```

Comment: I works just like that, thank you very much dude. Can i upvote you morethan once? :)

Comment: The second part is right, but `Grid.SetColumn` is just a shortcut for control.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, value) and is perfectly valid. It was only because they were added to the panel and not the grid that it failed.